# How do I get the caller ID from the phone line in WPF?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, side-by-side, tapi

I've tried Tapi3 in `WPF`, but it gives me the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'ITapi3.dll' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that the DLL you're attempting to use (`ITapi3.dll`) could not be found by your application.

From the name of the DLL, I assume you're using [this library](http://itapi3.codeplex.com/). Make sure that you have compiled the library code into a DLL (or [downloaded a pre-build binary from the website](http://itapi3.codeplex.com/releases/view/40060#DownloadId=104949)), and placed that DLL into your application's directory so that it can find it.

Any time that you use the functionality from a third-party DLL (i.e., something that is not provided as part of the standard .NET Framework), you must distribute that DLL along with your application. Putting it in the same folder as your app is the recommended practice, as it keeps your dependencies from causing conflicts with other applications and makes deployment much easier.

Comment: wouldn't it be also indicative of something wrong with the DLL? the file may be found but incompatible/corrupted for any reason?

Comment: @can: Yes, it could be. It could also be indicative of one of the DLL's dependencies not found. I went with the most likely explanation. Either way, downloading a new copy of the library's binaries and placing them in the app folder will likely fix the problem.

Comment: @Cody Gray: nevermind , the only problem is that the TE_CALLINFOCHANGE  event does'nt fire , but the TE_CALLNOTIFICATION fires . can you help me ?. thank you .